# API does not detect the headers

Tags: blazor, httpclient, rest, blazor-webassembly

I'm working on my first Blazor app. I try to request a rest API to get data.

I already use this API with other applications, so I'm sure it works fine.

My HTTP request is rejected by my API: the API does not detect the headers I want to add, so the request is rejected.

In my API, I check my user and password:

```
 protected override bool CheckAccessCore(OperationContext operationContext)
    {
        string AuthHeader = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers["Authorization"];
        if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(AuthHeader))
        {
                return CheckCredentials(AuthHeader);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

This code works fine with others apps.

In my Blazor project, I call My API this way :

In Program.cs, I declare my Httpclient :

```
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient{BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44346/MyServiceRest.svc")});
 builder.Services.AddScoped<ProjectModel.ClsMetierService>();
```

I add a constructor in my ClsMetierService class to get my scoped httpclient :

```
  HttpClient httpClient;
    public ClsMetierService(HttpClient _httpClient)
    {
        httpClient = _httpClient;
```

In my methode, I call my httpclient and set my headers :

```
 var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage()
        {
            Method = new HttpMethod("GET"),
            RequestUri = new Uri(urlStream)
        };

        requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Authorization", System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Admin:Password")));
requestMessage.Content.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Test", "Value");

            var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage);
            var responseStatusCode = response.StatusCode;

        JsonResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return JsonResult;
```

If I set a breakpoint in the `CheckAccessCore` in my API, the `AuthHeader` variable is null. I checked the `incomingrequest.Headers`, I get a list of 14 headers, none of them is "Authorization" or "test", as if my header were not added to my request:
[image]

I thought the problem was because of the `TryAddWithoutValidation` method, but my second header "test" does not exist either.

I usually use a HttpWebRequest and to this way :

```
httpReq.Headers.Add("Authorization", System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("login:password")));
```

But with Blazor WebAssembly I get this error: `System.Net.Request is not supported on this platform`

How can I set a custom header to my `HttpClient` request?

Comment: I tried another way with a httpRequestMessage : `(httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("Authorization", "loginpassword")` 
and 
`var response = await HttpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);` 
still the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, Blazor WASM is too limited and not adapted for my need, I must rewrite my existing API... I remade my app in blazor server, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-web-api?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=webassembly

The correct way to make Http requests from a Blazor WebAssembly app is to inject a `HttpClient` which is designed to work in WASM, not the standard `HttpClient`.

To add a header, refer to the section (".. with Fetch API request options"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-web-api?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=webassembly#httpclient-and-httprequestmessage-with-fetch-api-request-options-1)

```cs
requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
                new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.Value);

requestMessage.Content.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(
                "x-custom-header", "value");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Unfortunatly, I changed my code to get my httpclient by injection, still got the same problem.

I post the new code in my question, I edited it.